# form.cleaned_data returns empty set

Tags: django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I've got a form:

```
class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_building = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Here's my view:

```
def submit(request):
    args = {}
    args['form'] = OrderForm()
    if request.POST:
        order_form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            user = request.user
            address_city = order_form.cleaned_data.get('address_city')
            address_street = order_form.cleaned_data.get('address_street')
            address_building = order_form.cleaned_data.get('address_building')
            delivery_time = order_form.cleaned_data.get('delivery_time')
            new_order = Order(address_city=address_city,
                              address_street=address_street,
                              address_building=address_building,
                              delivery_date=delivery_time, client=user)
            new_order.save()
            Basket.objects.filter(client=user).delete()
            return redirect('/order/')
        else:
            args['form'] = order_form
    else:
        return render(request, 'order_page.html', args)
```

I guess that problem is with my template:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'order_submit' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}   
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="address">City<sup>*</sup></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="address" placeholder="City name" name="address_city">
            </div>
        </div>

        ...
```

I guess that the problem is that I don't use just `{{form}}`. But I need exactly these styles form my form. I do the same with my registration template and it works. Registration form inherits `UserCreationForm` and is bounded with `User` model, but my OrderForm inherits `form.Form`. What can it be?

```
Order model:
class Order(models.Model):
    state_choices = ('ACTIVE', 'COMPLETED', 'FROZEN')
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    delivery_time = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_street = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_building = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='ACTIVE')
    client = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
```

Comment: Add print statements or logging to your view to see whether the form is valid. If it's not, check what  `order_form.errors` contains.

Comment: When debugging, order_form.is_valid() returns True, and order_form.errors is empty

Comment: Why did you choose to subclass `OrderForm` from `forms.Form` instead of `forms.ModelForm`?

Comment: Because I need to display not all fields of my model. For example, in my model, I have ` client` field that must be set to ` request.user `. So, I had some problems with `forms.ModelForm`

Comment: @Andrew You could have specified fields that would be visible to user via `Meta.fields`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Besides that, what is the output of one of your form field in template? You can test it by putting `{{form.address_city}}` inside `<form></form>`

Comment: @ozgur, I need to set current user to ` client ` field. In save method, I can't do this, because I can't  use request.user in form

Comment: @andrew you can provide `request.user` as an initial value to your model form like:  `OrderForm(initial={'client': request.user}, data=request.POST)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values

Comment: @ozgur, I will try this, but I don't quite understand my current issue: why cleaned_data is empty?

Comment: Can you replace `<input type="text" id="address" placeholder="City name" name="address_city">` with `{{form.address_city}}` and tell me what is the difference?

Comment: @ozgur, when I write {{ form }} in <form></form> tags, it renders no form in result

Comment: @ozgur, I did as you said, and it returns no input field

Comment: If you want to keep the logic in a default Django form, you need to build the fields from `forms.CharField(max=123)` instead from `models.CharField(max=123)`. After you change that, you should see that `{{ form }}` prints out the form and could check its markup to create your own.

Comment: @ozgur, I tried as you advised with initial, but it throws an error saying that client field has null value. I attached my model code. What can it be?

Comment: @Andrew as `sthzg` pointed out, you should import your form fields from `forms` not `models`. Funny we couldn't see that by now.

Comment: @ozgur, Yeap, it works. But trying to do it with model, I pass request.user as initial, but there is an error, that client is null. Why?

Comment: @Andrew I jotted down an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem here is within the definition of the form. Forms don't work with model fields, but need form fields instead. Only then are the fields built correctly.

```
from django import forms

class OrderForm(forms.Form):
    delivery_time = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_city = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_street = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_building = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
```

After that try to output `{{ form }}` in your template.

```
    <form action="foo" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}   
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't matter what ids I set to my input fields. It depends on name values

Comment: Good to know, I removed the note from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't create a `form.Form` class to handle each fields explicitly. You can subclass from `forms.ModelForm` instead and let model form handle everything for you.

Problem was already pointed out by [sthzg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29870555/793428) however, I still insist on you using model forms over normal forms as much as possible.

Here is the rewritten version of your form class and view:

**forms.py**

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        exclude = ['order_date', 'client', 'state']
```

**views.py**

```
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(initial={'client': request.user}, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)
            order.client = request.user
            order.save()
            Basket.objects.filter(client=request.user).delete()
            return redirect('/order/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'order_page.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        return render(request, 'order_page.html', {'form': OrderForm()})
```

Comment: +1, it's the better way to go. Once you get it to work with a `ModelForm` check @ozgur 's answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you) Do u know why it returns null for client when I do as you said with initial?

Comment: Because initial values are not passed as property values of the newly created object. They are used for `form.is_valid()` to return `True` (especially in case where `client` is a required field). It is still your job to set those values explicitly before saving that object in the database.